# Recuperar valor de checkbox dinamico em php

Tags: php, ajax, checkbox

Tenho uma table onde uma de suas colunas é um checkbox, necessito fazer quando os checkbox estejam selecionados clique em um botão "Excluir Selecionados" onde seja possivel recuperar para mim todos os valores dos Checkbox selecionados.

Essa tabela HTML vem de uma requisição Ajax, onde é montada no HTML, então ela é dinamica.

```
while ($linha = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
  $codigo= utf8_encode($linha["codigo"])." "
  $return.= "<td>". "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cb\"  value=\"".$codigo."\"  >  "."</td>";

  $return.= "<td>" . utf8_encode($linha["data"]) . "</td>";
  $return.= "<td>" . utf8_encode($linha["hora"]) . "</td>";
  $return.= "<td>" . utf8_encode($linha["origem"]) . "</td>";
  $return.= "<td>" . utf8_encode($linha["destino"]) . "</td>";

}
```

Como é possível fazer isso? devo colocar minha tabela dentro de um formulário e enviar o formulário para outra pagina? 
Atualmente tentei fazer isso, então coloquei essa tabela em um form, e ao clicar no button é enviado os dados para uma pagina Excluir.php

tentei utilizar o seguinte comando para recuperar o valor
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key;// Aqui era para aparecer o valor do código, porém aparece apenas o nome de um button, ficando "cb"
}

Então, como faço para recuperar o código? existe um jeito mais correto de fazer isso? gostaria de saber também se é possivel enviar todos os valores selecionados via Ajax para o servidor, como resolver essa questão?

Answer (score 1):

Resumindo pelo o que entendi queres obter o valor da checkbox que o utilizador escolheu ?

Vou te dar um exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<form id="form" class="form" method="post" name="meuform">
<textarea id="texto" type="text" name="texto"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox" value="valor1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="checkbox" value="valor2" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return submitForm()" />
</form>
<div id="resposta"></div>
```

**Jquery**

```
function submitForm() {
var form = document.myform;

// obter todos os campos do form
var dataform = $(form).serialize();

// fazer um post ao arquivo.php (como exemplo)
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'arquivo.php',
    data: dataform,
    success: function(data){
       // resposta que obtiveste (so para confirmar que esta tudo ok. )
        $('#resposta').html(data);

    }
});

return false;

}
```

NO **arquivo.php** poderás dar um simples print_r na variável global POST
ex:

```
print_r($_POST);
// e depois podes tratar as checkboxes contidas em $_POST
// ex: $checkboxes = $_POST['checkbox']
```

Comment: Era essa mesma minha dúvida, muito obrigado pela resposta. mas com relação ao laço de repetição para obter o valor de todos meus checkbox, como é possivel fazer?

Comment: dá up na resposta, podes usar a função  [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) do jquery exemplo: `$('.classe').each(function(indice, obj) {
    
});`

Comment: Vou dar up, mas continuo enfrentando problemas, fiz um if para saber se estava recebendo o valor na pagina php mas não estou, como é possivel ver os valores dos dados serializados? é possivel enviar apenas o campo checkbox ?

Comment: Foi um erro meu, consegui identificar o problema. Obrigado pela solução